# Pdf print without opening in C#

Tags: c#-4.0

I'm try to print PDF without opening in adobereader. File print successfully, but adobereader open as a window. I want to stay close state that window.

this is my code..

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Reports/invPrnt.pdf"));
info.Verb = "Print";
info.CreateNoWindow = true;
info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
Process.Start(info);
```